# Show Registration form in front end wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, frontend

I've searched and search but to no avail. I cant find a simple way to have the registration form on a page in my wordpress site. I've seen a lot of plugins that kind of do it but they also make you customize the form or have a gazzlion bugs in them. I just want to reproduce the register form that appears at:

> www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register

I dont want a members plugin either as I am in the midst of creating my own CRM type plugin.

Comment: A possible way I can think of is to copy the html of the form but how would I get the form handling of the register for? I just don't want users near the ?action=register url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an (old) article about customizing your registration / login form:

http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/

Comment: That's fantastic thank you @Bram_Boterham. Don't think the jQuery tabs used in that article works so I rewrote it but the registration form and handling of it works. Thanks again